# Django How to display either an image or pdf

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a model with file upload field where users can upload either an image or a pdf. What is the best way to display the upload in a template when it can be either an image or a pdf.

I have seen a fairly complex ajax based solution. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

hello  you can use python-magic in your view to get the file type

next you could use the type  got  for use img tag or pdf tag  in you html

exemple with image and video:

```
class post(models.Model):
titre=models.CharField(unique=True,null=True,max_length=100)
description=models.TextField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=400)
T=models.CharField(default="image",blank=True,max_length=50)
image=models.FileField(null=True)
cat=models.ForeignKey(categorie,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
datepost=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,blank=True)
user=models.ForeignKey(myuser,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
vue=models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=True)
def __str__(self):
    return self.titre

def save(self, *args ,**kwargs):
    #cette partie permet de generer un identifiant unique
    f=self.image.read(1000)
    self.image.seek(0)
    mime=magic.from_buffer(f,mime=True)
    if "video" in mime :
        self.T="short"
    super(post,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

in my template:

```
{%if mpost.T == "image" %}
    <img src="{{mpost.image.url}}" style="max-width:100% ;max-height: 100%;flex-shrink: 0;">
{%else%}
    <video loop autoplay="true" src="{{mpost.image.url}}" style="max-width:100% ;max-height: 100%;flex-shrink: 0;"></video>
 {%endif%}
```